# Is the density of a mixture ever just the sum of the densities of each species in the mixture?

Tags: mixtures, density

My current hypothesis is that this is true when the volume is finite and perhaps this would cause the densities to be additive.

For example, imagine there is a closed container, 2 L in size. And within this container, there is 5 g of O2 and 3 g of N. The density of O2 would then be 5/2 g/L while the density of N would be 3/2 g/L. Would the density of the mixture of O2 and N not be total mass of the mixture divided by the volume which is (5+3)/2 = 8/2 = 4 g/mol which is equal to the sum of the densities?

Also, when would you find mixture density using $$ \frac{1}{\rho} = \frac{x_{A}} {{\rho_{A}}} + \frac{x_{B}} {{\rho_{B}}}$$ vs. using $$ {\rho} = x_{A}\rho_{A} + x_{B}\rho_{B} $$

I've seen the first version using the inverse of the density in a few places, but I don't see why the second version isn't equally applicable as it makes sense to me intuitively. Or, perhaps the second version is only for ideal gases?

(This is all assuming the mixture is ideal, so there are no changes in volume from mixing (ex. water and ethanol).)

Comment: Note that the term density is used for pure substances or whole mixtures, not for mixture components. For the latter, it is mass concentration.

Comment: Density of mixture is always equal to sum of mass concentrations of all mixture components, as it is direct consequence of mass conservation law, with both mass sides divided by the shared volume. For ideal gases, these mass concentrations are equal to the particular gas density, if the gas was at given conditions alone in the volume.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the term density is used for pure substances or whole mixtures, not for mixture components. For the latter, it is mass concentration.

Density of mixture is always equal to sum of mass concentrations of all mixture components, as it is direct consequence of mass conservation law, with both mass sides divided by the shared volume. For ideal gases, these mass concentrations are equal to the particular gas density, if the gas was at given conditions alone in the volume. Generally, it is not true and there are complicated relations of component densities and mixture density.

For mixing of [ideal Raoult liquids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raoult%27s_law#Ideal_mixing) with no volume change

$$V = V_1 + V_2$$

$$\rho = \frac {m_1 \cdot \rho_1 + m_2 \cdot \rho_2}{m}=w_1 \cdot \rho_1 + w_2 \cdot \rho_2$$

(  [mass fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_fraction_(chemistry)) is denoted $w$, while [mole fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mole_fraction) is denoted $x$ )